# Is there a way to emboss paper without using any tool or machine?

Tags: paper, printing

I want to try paper embossing at home but have no clue how to start with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess not "without any tool". You're gonna need something to apply weight or pressure on paper, your nails, fingers, a rod, etc., whatever doesn't scratch or leave many undesired artifacts. If your paper is heavy-weight, similar to cardboard, the results would be better.

First try it slowly with thin but dull objects like rounded tips of a hair clip, a ballpoint pen which doesn't write, or a pen cap, on a spare sheet same as your paper. The support you use also should be relatively smooth and not leaving visible dirt/ink marks on the surface: a couple of normal white papers on a desk would be fine. Start to slowly trace the pattern, then move to a larger tool like the back of a pen for filling in the shapes. If you are satisfied, proceed with your actual piece.

Comment: You’ll want to be conscious of what is placed under the paper you are embossing. Too hard a surface will not allow for the impression, too soft of a surface will puncture it.

Answer (score 3):

Weight. Like a flower press. 
You could put the paper you want to emboss between books with the motif or design touching the paper. You could use wood to protect the books.

Comment: On the slightly-absurd side, but not completely impractical, one could place the stack/sandwich on the ground and park a motor vehicle on it.